# integrating business logic in a classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, categorical-data, methodology

Are there any classification algorithms that can be hinted on business logic? Suppose I have historical information of states a particular object has been and my target variable is tomorrow's state, but states can only increase. For example:

```
-------------------------------------
| day1   | day2   | day3   | day4   |
-------------------------------------
| stage1 | stage2 | stage3 | stage3 |
-------------------------------------
| stage1 | stage1 | stage1 | stage2 |
-------------------------------------
| stage1 | stage2 | stage2 | stage2 |
-------------------------------------
| ...... | ...... | ...... | ...... |
-------------------------------------
```

I'm interested in learning from day1, day2, day3 and predicting day4.

However, I have a certain piece of business knowledge: stages do not go back.

So I can have a progression of:

```
stage1 -> stage2 -> stage3 -> stage4
or
stage1 -> stage1 -> stage1 -> stage2
etc
```

but I *cannot* have something like

```
stage1 -> stage2 -> stage3 -> *stage1*
or
stage1 -> stage2 -> stage2 -> *stage1*
```

Is there a classification algorithm that can take such a constraint into consideration?

Thank you very much for your time and support.

Answer (score 1):

So I cannot think of a custom tailored classifier that would fulfill this constraint, but you could formulate the problem slightly differently.

For each time step, you could restrict the options that a classifier would output. For example, if at time `t`, you are at Stage 2, you would only calculate the probabilities of jumping to Stage 3 (or Stage 4,etc.). By restricting the options that the classifier can output, you would effectively incorporate this logic.

As for a specific algorithm to use and which will perform well, that will depend on your data set.

Comment: Just to add: if the process only advances one stage at a time, you could reformulate the problem as classifying advance vs. not-advance, with the current stage (or the current and previous two stages) as a potential predictor.